# Elasticsearch response time issue for Multisearch Response , took ( Elasticsearch implementation in Grails app )

Tags: performance, grails, elasticsearch

For performance measuring, I measured the time difference between the time of request arrival and response formation in the Grails application in Grails controller as

```
long start = new DateTime().getMillis();
String result   = reportData()
JSONObject data = result ? JSON.parse(result) : new JSONObject()
long finish = new DateTime().getMillis();
```

Within `recordData()` Elasticsearch query is created and executed then response is parsed and required values are extracted. 
The problem is in Multisearch Response, when I add up all the 'took' time in each response, the result was greater than the (finish - start) time.
(all time in milliseconds). How is that possible?

> Note :
>   For the first time request, the sum of 'took' time is less than (finish - start ) time but when the same request is again made to application the issue appears and it persists.

Comment: you are talking about http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/empty-search.html#_took , right?  this is the part on your server.  what other tasks are done between start and end are no concern of that number.

Comment: the total time taken for the complete process ie. _finish_-_start_ must be greater than the sum of _took_ times from elasticsearch Multisearch response. but that is not happening here.